# Import and explore Oracle .dmp file

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-dump

I have a .dmp file (export from an Oracle DB) I need to get data from. I have installed Oracle 11g Express Edition successfully, with user SYSTEM and imp command I imported the file, with some warnings though, but now after hours of searching the Internet, I still have no idea how to explore the DB created by that file.

Can explain to me how to do that or at least point me to some relevant documentation, please? This is the first time I use Oracle.

Thanks!

Update: I already tried with Oracle SQL Developer. I use the user SYSTEM that was created automatically when I installed XE

Comment: You can use Oracle SQL Developer for development and management of Oracle Databases. [Check it out here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html)

Comment: Usually it is vice versa - people struggle with database installation (true, XE is mostly "click Next"), not to mention *importing* something - that's close to a rocket science for a newbie. But everyone is good at clicking different GUI buttons and they rarely have problems in *exploring* the database. I'm more than sure that you'll do it successfully in no time (as you've already heard, Oracle's SQL Developer is a free tool, you'll probably enjoy it). So - have a good time!

Comment: I. Manev, Littlefoot first thing I tried was Oracle SQL Developer, as I've done a lot of research before asking here, but I can't find any of the tables that were imported. Any other ideas ? I'm sure I'm missing something here. After import do I have to manually mount the DB ? Because when I try from Sql Plus the command STARTUP MOUNT I get a no privilege error msg